# Why does a confirm dialog have the words "says:

Tags: javascript

When I raise a `confirm` dialog in JavaScript, the title is `somesite.com says`. Is there a way (besides creating my own dialog) to remove this?

Comment: It's by design, you can't control this. Take a look at CSS/JavaScript/HTML alternatives like SweetAlert

Comment: Its not code, its browser that displays this. You will need to modify browser's code. FYI different browser has different text instead of somesite.com says:

Comment: i know it's the browser. The question is if there's a way to remove that text

Comment: hmm... It should have been "asks,"